# Component that adds its own Provider

Tags: reactjs

I am tasked with supporting multiple component kits, while applying a single design system. To help me accomplish this, I have implemented a `ThemeControllerProvider` which provides a generic theme object in the `Context` to my actual theme providers `ThemeProviderA` and `ThemeProviderB`.

This means that a user's app will be configured with something like this.

```
<ThemeControllerProvider mode="dark">
  <ThemeProviderA>
    <ThemeProviderB>
      <App/>
    </ThemeProviderB>
  </ThemeProviderA>
</ThemeControllerProvider>
```

This is working fine, but I would like to improve the developer experience. I want to allow developers to not be concerned about the controller.

```
<ThemeProviderA>
  <ThemeProviderB>
    <App/>
  </ThemeProviderB>
</ThemeProviderA>
```

Or when they are using only a single component kit...

```
<ThemeProviderA>
  <App/>
</ThemeProviderA>
```

My `ThemeControllerProvider` has a reducer in its `Context`, and I have been successful having each theme provider to detect whether the controller is present or not by checking whether the reducer is null or not, but I haven't figured out what to do with that information. The downstream components need a `controller.state.theme` prop, but it doesn't exist when the comp is initialized without a provider already being in place.

```
// ThemeProviderA.jsx

const controller = useThemeController()

if (controller === null) {
  return (
    <ThemeControllerProvider>
      <ThemeProviderA theme={???}>
        {children}
      </ThemeProviderA>
    <ThemeControllerProvider>
  )
} else {
  return (
    <ThemeProviderA theme={controller.state.theme}>
      {children}
    </ThemeProviderA>
  )
}
```

Is there a pattern I can implement where the theme providers can auto detect the lack of a `ThemeControllerProvider` and automatically inject one? And also, if theme providers are nested, I need only the highest order provider to inject the controller.

Answer (score 0):

ok, it's a very interesting problem.

Suppose your `ThemeControllerProvider` is also a context provider. I can walk through the idea first,

```
  const a = useContext(Context)
```

The `a` would cause no error without a registered provider as a parent. why?

```
  Context = React.createContext(defaultContextValue)
```

Without a provider registered, what the value `a` reads will be `defaultContextValue`. In your case, we can set a default empty `theme` or whatever.

```
  const defaultContextValue = { theme: ... }
```

##### implementation

Of course my assumption is that your controller is a context.

```
const ThemeControllerContext = React.createContext({ theme: null })
```

Your rest of code should still work with this change.

```
if (controller === null) {
  return (
    <ThemeControllerContext.Provider value={theme}>
      <ThemeProviderA theme={???}>
        {children}
      </ThemeProviderA>
    <ThemeControllerContext>
  )
} else {
  return (
    <ThemeProviderA theme={controller.state.theme}>
      {children}
    </ThemeProviderA>
  )
}
```

##### read material

https://javascript.plainenglish.io/react-context-is-a-global-variable-b4b049812028

You can find your case marked by case D in the above article.